# List resources managed by specific Google Cloud Platform API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

Our developers enabled certain APIs in their GCP project that are no longer needed.

I tried disabling Google Cloud Memorystore for Redis API (redis.googleapis.com) but got an error:

```
Error Disabling Api
[Not ready to deactivate the service on this project; ensure there are no more resources managed by this service.] with failed services [redis.googleapis.com]
```

Is there any way to list the resources currently managed by the API service so I can remove them and disable this API?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any API that will tell you which resources are under Service Usage. Some resources require more than one service to be enabled. I do not recommend disabling services once enabled. There is not a one-to-one relationship between an API and a resource (eg VM instance). Some resources need to access more than one API (VM instance/KMS/Cloud Storage). There are side effects such as disabling/deleting service accounts that may affect resources that you need. Instead, remove permissions (roles) to those services from users/service accounts.

The Google Cloud Console will show you which APIs are being used historically. Go to APIs & Services -> Dashboard. You will find a table of APIs being used, but not the resource using them.

The process of mapping API usage to Resources is a manual process. I would use Cloud Asset Inventory to manage my resources and not worry about APIs that are enabled.